# AvalonEdit в UAP

Tags: c#, wpf

Нужно использовать AvalonEdit в универсальном приложении, ищу способ как можно прикрутить его.

Answer (score 2):

Нет такого способа если только не переписать весь контрол с нуля. WPF и UAP из общего имеют только XAML, они не совместимы. UAP со всех сторон урезаный поэтому переписать мало реально. Короче вобще без вариантов, можно только попытатся искать другой контрол.

Comment: Грусно. Но спасибо за ответ. По-любому еще никто такой контрол не написал, а сам я вряд ли потяну...